# python3.7.3 ssl.SSLContext() get "killed"

Tags: python, ssl, arm

I try to use ssl module with urllib.request , And my script always die.
So i found this:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 26 2020, 06:35:45)
[GCC 6.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'LibreSSL 3.1.1'
>>> ssl.SSLContext()
Killed
```

That all infomation i got. And I've g00gle about this , nothing I can found in the world.
Can somebody help me with this trouble? I really need someone help me.

Comment: It might be that the openssl/LibreSSL version installed on the system does not match the version which was used to compile Python. Just a guess though since practically nothing is known about the system.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Your guess is grate...And I solved it by golang....Cross compile is too hard for me and too much trouble to fix.